# Facebook share button href won't be able to be changed dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

User could change the HTML form and I did thw 2 way binding with the URL params.

I can inspect the data-href changed dynamically.

However when I click the share button, the shared page still remain the original URL.

It returned `undefined` by `FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('FB_BTN'));`

However, I can truly get the element of `document.getElementById('FB_BTN')`

How could I change the shared page url params with angular?

## HTML

```
    <div id="FB_BTN" class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://0.0.0.0:3003/user/quick_search/index#/?depart_date_range=2016%2F06%2F13%20-%202016%2F06%2F16&amp;return_date_range=2016%2F06%2F13%20-%202016%2F06%2F16" data-layout="icon_link" data-mobile-iframe="true"></div>
```

## Javascript

```
    (function(d, s, id){
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/sdk.js";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    app.run(function ($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event, absNewUrl, absOldUrl) {
          if(typeof(FB) !== 'undefined' && angular.element('#FB_BTN')){
            var share_btn_ele = angular.element('#FB_BTN')
            share_btn_ele.attr('data-href', absNewUrl)
            FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('FB_BTN'));
          }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Insert a new button instead of changing the existing one

Comment: @Hi WizKid, it sounds strange and not practical, but maybe it's the only to do so.

Comment: Pretty much, yeah. The SDK “marks” elements it has already parsed – so instead of trying to “clean” the existing element of that, replacing it by a new one, and then getting that parsed explicitly, is the easiest way to do it.